# Database design guidelines

Tags: database, database-design

I have managed to get my database somewhat designed.  So far, it looks like the following
[image]

This is the scenario. The focal point is my projects table.  A project belongs to a single client. So I might create a project for say SO.  This project can have many users (image shows wrong relationship) that work on the project.  Each of these users belongs to a department.  So me and Bob may be working on a project for SO, I belong to Marketing and Bob belongs to Finance.

Here is where I am getting confused.  Each department has a set of documents it needs to complete for a project.  Marketing might need to do a Document a and Document B, and finance might need to do a Document C.

Say I do something like this
[image]

I am basically saying that a department has one or more documents.  But then you can see it gets messy.  How can I show that Marketing has documentA and documentB and Finance has documentThree?

Would I need to define marketing and finance as a one to one relationship with the departments table, and then do documents coming from this?  That would produce something along the lines of this

[image]

Is that the correct approach to be taking?  Essentially, I need to link different documents to different departments, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't like either approach; as they create separate tables for each doc type when the data in the tables is nearly typed the same.  I would be more in favor of one table in these cases.

I would have a documents table with a type in it which indicates document type and is a forein key to DocumentType table which lists all document types.

Depending on how document types are chosen for project and department, I would have a DepartmentDocuments table which list the documents which each department COULD use.  I would also have a ProjectDepartmentDocuments table which indicates the mandated and optional documents used for a particular project, along with their information specific to the department/project.

I also question the relationship from users to projects.  It appears a project can only have one user.  If that's the case your design is fine.  However if a project can have many users, you should have a projectUsers table to handle many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had a follow up question.  This app will produce documents.  Say the documents are very different from each other and I collect data for each document via forms, would this require a seperate table for each document?  Thanks

Comment: There's two approaches for that.  One would be to have a doc table which lists the fields for each doc, and a separate table to store the values for those keyed pairs.    The challenge with this approach is reporting can be cumbersome as the data is vertical instead of horizontal, meaning if reporting and aggregation on the documents would be needed, you might be better off with the second approach.   If however each document is independent of others and aggregation isn't needed 1st options is likely best.  The second option is separate tables.  The challenge here is new tables/code each doc.

Comment: Thanks, I created a new topic which gives more details to this specific problem.  If you have time, it would be great if you could check it out.  Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221734/database-design-managing-documents/32225258?noredirect=1#comment52334136_32225258