# Database design - Managing documents

Tags: database, database-design

I asked a more generic question yesterday and done some work based on this.  This question is more to the point in regards to something I am trying to work out.

So my application has a departments table to handle departments.  So I am able to make different departments within my application such as Marketing and Finance.

The problem is, I know what departments I need to make, and these will be created beforehand (but I have made it like a CMS so an admin can edit departments etc).  With the departments created, I envision something like this
[image]

So a user can choose the department from a dropdown (remember, this is after departments are created).  When they do this, the document dropdown should populate.

This is my problem, how can I associate specific documents to a department?  Each document requires different inputs, so I would imagine they need to be different tables?  At the moment I have
[image]

But this doesnt really solve my problem whereby I can state that the Marketing department has a Brief document and Overview document.

How could I go about doing this seeing that I do not specifically have a table for each department?  Would I need to create one for each department?

Thanks

Comment: The [More generic question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204191/database-design-guidelines/32204891?noredirect=1#comment52339433_32204891)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

If the variety of the document's information you need to store is to large
create a table which has 5 columns:

```
id,department_id,crated_at, updated_at, property
```

so for each property you will have a record in the table e.g:

```
id   department_id      crated_at        updated_at      property
1         454           2015-08-20       2015-08-22      x:34
2         454           2015-08-26       2015-08-26      z:234
3         934           2015-08-25       2015-08-26      y:45
```

This way you won't need table for each document type

EDIT: another option is adding one column for property name and one for it's value

```
id,department_id,crated_at, updated_at, property_name, property_value
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  If I do something similar to what you suggest, would I then have a new table for each document which links to that table?  Reason I ask is because each document requires different information, and I need to capture this within tables.

Comment: You will have 1 table containing all data about all documents.
one for departments and one as I mentioned  above.
Why do you need separate table for each document type?